# GraphQL Spring Subscription: Unexpected message before connection_ack

Tags: spring, graphql, subscription

I am trying to consume a GraphQL subscription from the publically available API at https://hasura.io/learn/graphql using Spring's WebSocketGraphQlClient. I can execute queries with HttpGraphQlClient but with subscriptions I'm running into an issue as depicted in the following stack trace:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected message before connection_ack: GraphQlWebSocketMessage[type="ping", payload={message=keepalive}]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected message before connection_ack: GraphQlWebSocketMessage[type="ping", payload={message=keepalive}]
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.graphql.client.WebSocketGraphQlTransport$GraphQlSessionHandler.lambda$handle$3(WebSocketGraphQlTransport.java:246) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:386) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.8.jar:3.5.8]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:292) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:401) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:734) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.WebsocketClientOperations.onInboundNext(WebsocketClientOperations.java:163) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.9.jar:1.1.9]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1383) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295) ~[netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
```

This is my code:

```
WebSocketGraphQlClient subscriptionClient = WebSocketGraphQlClient
            .builder("wss://hasura.io/learn/graphql", new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient())
            .headers(headers -> {
headers.setBearerAuth("some_token");
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            })
            .build();
subscriptionClient.start().subscribe(res -> {});
```

The subscription is executing flawlessly on https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/graphiql. There, you can also get a token generated for you. Interestingly, you can also see on the attached screenshot that the message sequence is as described by the exception message with the connection_ack message coming in after another message. However, the browser client seems to be fine with that.

[image: Web client screenshot]